# How to use getChildFragment for googlemaps?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-fragments, location

So i have a tabbed activity app in android studio
with one tab being a map in a fragment
How do i get the map to ask for permission to display current location using a getChildFragment?
Iv tried adding a getChildFragmentManager in my onCreateView but i dont think it does anything.

Heres my java

```
package com.example.vadtest.ui.main;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.vadtest.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link tab2#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

public class tab2<locationCallback> extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    View view;
    GoogleMap map;
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
    Location myLocation;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS = 0x1;
    private final static int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 0x2;
    private TextView txtLocation;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;



    public tab2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment tab2.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static tab2 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        tab2 fragment = new tab2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));




    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    if (mapView != null) {
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);


    }
    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        map = googleMap;

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(120000); // two minute interval
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(120000);
        LocationRequest locationRequest = mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);




    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }




}
```

im completely stuck here. Im brand new to android studio so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your getChildFragmentManager, what do you actually do? This affects whether you can display the map correctly